# DDNS client for Google Domains for windows

Tags: dns

I looked into DDclient but its not an easy solution to implement even after installing Perl on windows as its now asking me to install some Data::Validate::IP module and I am new to Perl.

Is there any easy to use DDNS client for windows which I can use on my clients computer to update their systems IP on a google domain I purchased?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple DDNS Windows client that works with Google Domains DDNS:

https://github.com/saudiqbal/SaudsGoogleDomainsDynamicDNSUpdater

I've added it to my windows startup folder so I don't have to remember to manually run it after every reboot.